Can't send email message by mailx (cannot get RSA certificate from file / domain name not found)
I tried to send an email message as test using mailx. The mail server is located on linux server which contains dovecot and postfix installed and configured.
I executed the instruction as follows on same mail server:
echo "email test" | mailx -v -s "email test" \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp=smtp://192.168.1.10:587 \
-S from="dave@domain.com" \
-S smtp-auth-user=dave@domain.com \
-S smtp-auth-password=the_password \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S nss-config-dir="/etc/pki/nssdb/" \
dave@domain.com

Checking the /var/log/maillog file. It shows the messages as follow:
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file "/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem": disabling TLS support
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:288:fopen('/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem','r'):
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: warning: TLS library problem: error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:290:
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140DC002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl/ssl_rsa.c:596:
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: lost connection after STARTTLS from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/cleanup[41669]: 18DAF200E2C92: message-id=<20240924144711.18DAF200E2C92@domain.com>
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/submission/smtpd[41666]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 commands=1/2
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/qmgr[20615]: 18DAF200E2C92: from=<double-bounce@domain.com>, size=914, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/smtp[41674]: 18DAF200E2C92: to=<postmaster@domain.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0.02/0/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=domain.com type=AAAA: Host not found)
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/bounce[41675]: warning: 18DAF200E2C92: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 24 10:47:11 serverMail postfix/qmgr[20615]: 18DAF200E2C92: removed

I see two things.
First, I get cannot get
'RSA certificate from file "/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem"'
and
'Permission denied:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:288:fopen('/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem','r''
I executed ll /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/ and I get
-rw-------. 1 root root 1221 set 19 09:45 dovecot.pem

Even I change the permission to 755 by chmod. Even though, it's  not working.
Second, I get:
'(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=domain.com type=AAAA: Host not found)'

I executed cat /etc/hosts.  It shows the lines as follow:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.10  serverMail
192.168.1.10 domain.com

Even I added '192.168.1.10 domain.com' but it's not working either.
What can I do so that I can send email messages as test.

Ok I could it dissapear the messages of 'cannot get RSA certificate from file "/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem": disabling TLS support' and '(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=domain.com type=AAAA: Host not found)'. What I did is opening the /etc/selinux/config file and changing the value from 'enforcing' to 'disabled' and finally I restarted the server
